# Affine varieties and their ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was reading on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient) about quotient ideals. It mentions that if $W$ and $V$ are affine varieties (assume $V$ is) and $I(V)$ and $I(W)$ are the ideals for $V$ and $W$, then $$I(V):I(W) = I(V\setminus W).$$

They also talk about $Z(I:J) = \text{cl}(Z(I)-Z(J))$. Is it not right if we remove closure? That is, it is not right $Z(I:J) = Z(I)-Z(J)$?

Comment: $Z(I:J)$ is closed by definition, but the set difference $Z(I)-Z(J)$ is usually not closed, but rather locally closed. This alone tells us we don't have equality without closure.

Comment: @basket, oh okay, so that's why we get the proper $\supseteq$. Is there an example where is it not proper?

Comment: Dear jacob, I have taken the liberty to change your $I(V):I(W) = I(V/W)$ (in the third line) into the correct $I(V):I(W) = I(V \setminus W)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) For $I=(y), J=(x)\subset \mathbb C[x,y]$ we have $$(I:J)=I\quad \quad   Z(I)=Z(I:J)=\mathbb C\times \{0\}\quad \quad  Z(J)=\{0\}\times \mathbb C$$ and thus we get the equalities and **strict** inclusion $$Z(I:J)=\mathbb C\times \{0\}=\overline {\mathbb C^*\times \{0\}}=\overline {Z(I)\setminus Z(J)}\supsetneq\mathbb C^*\times \{0\}=Z(I)\setminus Z(J)$$

2) On the other hand  for $K=(y-1)$, and thus $(I:K)=I, Z(K)=\mathbb C\times \{1\}$, we have the **equalities**  $$ Z(I:K)=\mathbb C\times \{0\}=\mathbb C\times \{0\}\setminus \mathbb C\times \{1\}=Z(I)\setminus Z(K)   $$

Comment: Wait, why is $(I: J ) = I$?

Comment: Because  $f(x,y)\in I \iff  y$ divides $f(x,y) \iff y$ divides $xf(x,y)\iff f(x,y)\in (I:J)$

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples in the ring $\mathbb C[x,y]$:

1. Consider $I=(x-1)$ and $J=(x-1,y-1)$. Then $I:J=(x-1)$. Moreover $$Z(I:J)=Z(x-1)=Z(I)=\{(1,\alpha)|\alpha \in \mathbb C\},$$
   while $$Z(I)\smallsetminus Z(J)=\{(1,\alpha)|\alpha \in \mathbb C\}\smallsetminus \{(1,1)\}.$$
2. Consider $I=((x-1)(x-2))$ and $J=(x-1)$. Then $I:J=(x-2)$. We have
   $$Z(I:J)=Z(x-2)=\{(2,\alpha)|\alpha \in \mathbb C\},$$
   and
   $$Z(I)\smallsetminus Z(J)=\big\{\{(2,\alpha)|\alpha \in \mathbb C\}\cup\{(1,\alpha)|\alpha \in \mathbb C\} \big\}\smallsetminus Z(J)$$
   Then in this case
   $$Z(I)\smallsetminus Z(J)= Z(I:J)$$

Comment: Your  part  2.  seems to be false. Indeed, in your very last line $Z(I)\setminus Z(J)$ is the set of points $(\alpha,1)$ **with $(1,1)$ deleted**, whereas $Z(I:J)$ is the set of **all** $(\alpha,1)$, including  $(1,1)$ .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You're right! Sorry for that, I wrote it just while having a break from a really annoying math problem. Maybe my brain was burning.

Comment: Dear Sfarla, don't worry: everybody has such moments, [Grothendieck included !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number)#In_mathematics)

Comment: Wait, why is $(I: J ) = I$

Comment: According to the definition of ideal quotient, $(I:J)=\{a\in\mathbb C[x,y]|aJ\subseteq I\}$. Trivially $I\subseteq (I:J)$. Moreover, if $a\in (I:J)$,then $a(y-1)\in (x-1)$. $(x-1)$ is a prime ideal, $(y-1)\notin I$, then...